# Fusion Charts Export

Tags: c#, asp.net, fusioncharts

I am trying to export the fusion charts in my project, almost i have done but
i am facing problem with caption and sub caption.

I knew we have properties caption and sub caption in fusion charts, but if i use these captions display in screens level also but here i want only when export the chart so my question is **How can i get Caption and sub caption when only in export the chart?**

Is there any properties to show caption and sub caption only when export the chart.

Please help on this.

Thanks,
Bharat

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts API methods can be used for this, you can use `setChartAttribute` method to set `caption` and `subCaption` for chart and then trigger the chart export using `exportChart` method.

Check this [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sikrigagan/1atbtzsq/) for the same.

To know more about these methods, please check out [this developer documentation page](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-methods.html).